# Define variable which belongs to indexed set in Gurobi with C#

Tags: c#, indexing, gurobi

I have a definition of variable v which has two indexes: p and k. Index p belongs to set P, and index k belongs to set K, for every m depot. 
[image]

the I define the variable in Gurobi like this:

```
GRBVar[,] v;
     for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)
     v = new GRBVar[P,K[m]];     //variable of vehicle

for (int p = 0; p < P; p++)
{
 for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)
  {
    for (int k = 0; k < K[m]; k++)
    v[p,k] = model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "v" + p + "," + k);
                }
            }
```

but it cannot run, it said Use of unassigned local variable 'v'.
I would really appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You should make sure your M is never less than 1 as your program will crash otherwise.

(2) Try replacing your first line with :

```
GRBVar[,] v = null;
```

Your program will run, but I don't think it makes much sense - you are replacing your v in your loop, so only the last vehicle will be inside v.